# Solving trignometric terms with maxima

Tags: trigonometry, maxima

I try to get all roots of cos(x) with wxMaxima

```
(%i29)solve(cos(x)=0,x);
solve: using arc-trig functions to get a solution.
Some solutions will be lost.
(%o29) [x=%pi/2]
```

The solution gets solved by using arccos.

How can i get all solutions for a given domain? e.g. [0; 5*pi]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using to_poly_solve you can obtain all solutions:

> to_poly_solve(cos(x)=0,x);

Comment: Note that OP will need `load(to_poly_solve);` before that in order to use that function.