# wxMaxima solve sin function

Tags: function, solver, trigonometry

In wxMaxima the solution

```
solve(sin(x)=0,x);
```

will result to x=0.
Is there a way to get the "full" solution?

```
x = n %pi , n=0,1,2,...
```

Comment: does this help? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872011/solving-trignometric-terms-with-maxima

Comment: This answered my question. Thank you.