# Unable to solve equations involving trigonometric funcions

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I am trying to solve an equation involving trigonometric functions with Maxima, but I am not able to get the solutions. For example, `solve(sin(x) = cos(x),x)` returns `[sin(x) = cos(x)]` instead of `%pi/4`, and even equations with only one solution fail, since for example `solve(sin(x) = x,x)` returns `[sin(x) = x]` instead of `0`.

Why does this happen?

Comment: And what about `to_poly_solve`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872011/solving-trignometric-terms-with-maxima

Comment: @jacob I just tried as you said, but `load(to_poly_solve)$ to_poly_solve(sin(x)=x,x);` still doesn't work for me. It returns this messages: `WARNING: redefining MAXIMA::OPAPPLY in DEFMACRO`, `WARNING: redefining MAXIMA::OPAPPLY in DEFMACRO`, `Unable to solve`, and the resulting output is `%solve([sin(x)=x],[x])`.

Comment: The first equation from your original question can be solved using `to_poly_solve`. The second one can't be solved by neither `solve` nor `to_poly_solve` but you could obtain the numerical solution using `find_root`. Then you will get 0 as a result.